# Update multiple column from another table using sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one master table named `table1` where i store or update `mobileNo` data daily for a month.

```
;WITH table1 AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES
(9999999999, '01/10/2013', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(9999999999, NULL, '02/10/2013', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(9999999999, NULL, NULL, '03/10/2013', NULL, NULL),
(9999999999, NULL, NULL, NULL, '04/10/2013', NULL),
(9999999999, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '30/10/2013'),
(9999999999, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(8888888888, '01/10/2013', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(8888888888, NULL, '02/10/2013', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(8888888888, NULL, NULL, '03/10/2013', NULL, NULL),
(8888888888, NULL, NULL, NULL, '04/10/2013', NULL),
(8888888888, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '30/10/2013')) 
as t(mobileno,date1,date2,date3,date4,date30))
```

And i have another table named `table2`  where i keep unique `mobileNo` against table1. Now i want to update `table2` against `table1` if any data exists in `table1`.

```
mobileno        date1      date2      date3      date4      date30
--------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
8888888888      01/10/2013 02/10/2013 03/10/2013 04/10/2013 30/10/2013
9999999999      01/10/2013 02/10/2013 03/10/2013 04/10/2013 30/10/2013
```

However i tried the query like this

```
UPDATE table1
set table1.date1 = 
(SELECT date1 from table2 where table2.mobileno = table1.mobileno) 
Where table2.mobileno = table1.mobileno
```

How do i update in a single query without repeating to update the 30 nos. of  date columns, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might consider an other more normalized structure for your tables.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps NULL values from TABLE2 can be avoided to UPDATE NOT NULL values in TABLE1 using following UPDATE statement.

Only ISNULL function is added to previous post

```
update table1
set 
    date1 = ISNULL(t2.date1, date1),
    date2 = ISNULL(t2.date2, date2)
from table2 t2
where table1.mobileno = t2.mobileno
```